# Accessing Custom User Fields in Parse Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have added a custom user field to parse called isInfluencer that initiates when a new user is created by utilizing the following code:

```
newUser[@"isInfluencer"] = @YES;
```

I am trying to access it in another class using the code below but it always logs 0 to the console rather than 1:

```
BOOL influencer = [self.currentUser[@"isInfluencer"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"%hhd", influencer);
```

Is there some other way that I should be accessing this variable in order to return the correct bool value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I needed to query the user table with the following code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
```

From there it was as simple as plugging in what I wanted the query to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"<custom coloumn name>" equalTo:<row name>];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
          for (PFUser *user in objects) {
            [user objectForKey:@"<custom coloumn name>"];
            NSLog(@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"<custom coloumn name>"]);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```